# How to Configure both operators(AND,OR) for solr search in drupal 7

Tags: search

I am using solr search on my site but i need to know how we can use both operators at the same time that is if its not an AND search it should redirect for OR search.
Is there any module for this or views.

Here is my use case:

I have already configured my site on AND search. When there is no search results, that is if user is searching for the phrase *"Admin guide"* and this phrase is not available, then the search should redirect for OR search and it should count page as match wherever it finds *admin* or *guide* word.

Comment: Could you explain your use case a little more?  What do you mean if it is not an AND search?  How exactly is it determined what type of search you want?

Comment: Do you mean that if `x AND y` would return no result, solr should search for `x OR y`?

Comment: Boriana:My use case is that if i am searching for the word 'admin guide' and if there is no such word on the site then it should show me the results for 'OR' search like it can display wherever admin word is found and wherever "guide" word found.

Comment: Molot: yes exactly if x AND y returning zero results then it should go for x OR Y which will resturn some results and the search will not be return empty results.

Comment: I need to know is it possible to provide operator at run time.
I am using AND operator with my solr search,

Comment: I need to know is it possible to provide operator at run time.
I am using AND operator with my solr search.
So if user is searching for "Admin guide" and on our site if that word does not exist then search will prompt Spell check or in Did you mean Section Something related to admin word.
But what output i am expecting is that if "Admin guide" word is not there then search should return wherever "Admin" or "Guide" word found that is OR search.
So in technical terms if AND search doesn't give any result then the search should be proceeded with OR search.
So this is my requirement.